# Solving system of ODEs using Octave

Tags: octave, ode

I am trying to solve a system of two ODEs using Octave, and in particular the function lsode.

The code is the following:

```
function xdot = f (x,t)

a1=0.00875;
a2=0.075;
b1=7.5;
b2=2.5;
d1=0.0001;
d2=0.0001;
g=4*10^(-8);
K1=5000;
K2=2500;
n=2;
m=2;

xdot = zeros(2,1);

xdot(1) = a1+b1*x(1)^n/(K1^n+x(1)^n)-g*x(1)*x(2)-d1*x(1);
xdot(2) = a2+b2*x(1)^m/(K2^m+x(1)^m)-d2*x(2);

endfunction

t = linspace(0, 5000, 200)';
x0 = [1000; 1000];
x = lsode ("f", x0, t);

set term dumb;
plot(t,x);
```

I am getting continuously the same error, that "x" is not defined, and I do not know why. The error is the following:

```
warning: function name 'f' does not agree with function file name '/home /Simulation 1/sim.m'
error: 'x' undefined near line 17 column 17
error: called from
    sim at line 17 column 9
```

It would we great that any of you could help me with this code.

Comment: On which line? Edit to include the entire error message. And I assume that the code after `endfunction` is in a different file or pasted into the Command Window?

Comment: The whole code is in the same file... That was the problem. Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors. One, you are not saving your source code with the proper name. Two, variable "x" is a vector, and nothing in your script indicates that. You should add a line "x = zeros(1,2);" right after "xdot = zeros(2,1);".

Try the following code:

```
function ODEs
  t = linspace(0, 5000, 200);
  x0 = [1000; 1000];
  x = lsode (@f, x0, t);

  fprintf('t = %e \t\t x = %e\n',t,x);

endfunction

function xdot = f(x,t)

  a1=0.00875;
  a2=0.075;
  b1=7.5;
  b2=2.5;
  d1=0.0001;
  d2=0.0001;
  g=4*10^(-8);
  K1=5000;
  K2=2500;
  n=2;
  m=2;

  xdot = zeros(2,1);
  x = zeros(1,2);

  xdot(1) = a1+b1*x(1)^n/(K1^n+x(1)^n)-g*x(1)*x(2)-d1*x(1);
  xdot(2) = a2+b2*x(1)^m/(K2^m+x(1)^m)-d2*x(2);

endfunction
```

Save it as **ODEs.m** and execute it. It does not plot anything, but gives you an output with the results for the *t* range you supplied.